# How to get user groups from Django?

Tags: html, django, ajax

I'm trying to get the user groups that exist in a user in Django but unfortunately in the console it says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined
    at 6/:643:33
```

The function is supposed to redirect the user depending on if he has those groups or not.

This is my current code:

```
if (data.includes('The process is done.')) {
alert('Success!.');
setTimeout(function () {
  if (user.groups.filter(name='group1').exists() || user.groups.filter(name='group2').exists()) {
    window.location.href = "{% url 'red' %}";
  } else {
  window.location.href = "{% url 'blue' %}";
  }
  }, 2000);
  }
```

The code above is inside a success AJAX function.

Comment: `user` is not known in JavaScript: Django is a *backend* framework, it renders data at the server side. JavaScript does not know anything about models, views, etc. It just got a HTTP response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I get that but how would I parse those groups into the the JS? Do I have to make a separate function in views.py for the groups to filter them or? (FYI: I'm not a fullstack engineer)

Comment: You make a view where your AJAX makes a request to, that will then look for the user (and the corresponding groups) and for example pass the names of the groups, or just `True`/`False` if you want to filter. It of course depends on the "overall application" what you want to do.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Currently the AJAX redirects based on a function from the views where it would redirect after a submission...so I have to make another function separate from the main one or? I'm not sure I'm getting the big picture.

Comment: you can get user groups object by calling {{ request.user.groups }} on the html side. the point of {{ }} is to render the django template object to html . And no you can't just call django template variable on javascript directly

Answer (score 0):

one way to get user groups is by sending the relevant user information along with the AJAX response, you can modify your django view to include the user's group information in the response like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def ajax_function(request):
    #your logic goes here

    user_groups = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
    data = {
        # other informations that you might need
        'message': 'The process is done.',
        'user_groups': user_groups,
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

now you can access to `user_groups` in your JavaScript:

```
if (data.message === 'The process is done.') {
alert('Success!.');
setTimeout(function () {
  if (data.user.groups.includes('group1') || data.user.groups.includes('group2')){
    window.location.href = "{% url 'red' %}";
  } else {
  window.location.href = "{% url 'blue' %}";
  }
  }, 2000);
  }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot. I had to do some fine-tuning for a while but I managed to make it work. :)